# How to write a table encoded as a list of dictionaries directly to a zipped archive containing a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, zip, sparse-matrix

Suppose you have data in the form of a list of dictionaries like `d` here:

```
d = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}, {'a' : 3, 'c' : 5}]
```

and you want to save it as a comma-separated table to a zipped (not gzipped, I mean a **.zip** archive) CSV *without going via, e.g., a `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`*.

Why not via `pandas`? Because `d` in real practice may correspond to a very large, but especially *sparse*, DataFrame, i.e. a table with many more columns than non-NA data per row, which for some reason occupies a huge amount of memory (BTW this is not a theory: it made our scripts crash several times, hence our need to work around it).

`d` is a sort of unpivoted-in-disguise version of the data, because each dictionary only contains the relevant data, not a useless sequence of NA's.

From the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) I learned how to write `d` directly to a CSV:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile :
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['a','b','c'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(d)
```

but I don't see any option to write to a *zipped* CSV.

I consulted the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) of `zipfile`, but I could not make it work, due to the usual problem between text and bytes.

```
if os.path.exists('test.csv.zip') :
    os.remove('test.csv.zip')
with zipfile.ZipFile('test.csv.zip', mode = 'a') as zip :
    with zip.open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile :
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['a','b','c'])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(d)

# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Can anyone think of a workaround, or maybe a radically different approach that I am not seeing?**

The fundamental constraints are:

1. `d` is always going to be generated: this we cannot decide or change
2. avoid generating very large objects that consume as much memory or disk space as the dense `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`
3. the data must be written to a csv.zip archive.

Otherwise we would write to a CSV, hoping that it is not too huge (but yeah, that was the initial issue, so...), and zip it afterwards.

---

**EDIT** posting the implementation from Daweo's answer, for completeness.

```
import os
import zipfile
import csv
import codecs
utf8 = codecs.getwriter('utf_8') # or other encoding dictated by requirements

output_zip_file = 'test.csv.zip'

if os.path.exists(output_zip_file) :
    os.remove(output_zip_file)
with zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip_file, mode = 'a') as zip :
    with zip.open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile :
        writer = csv.DictWriter(utf8(csvfile), fieldnames = ['a','b','c'])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(d)
```

Comment: You can't use the `zipfile` module to directly write to a CSV file member within it. `.zip` files are *archives* (i.e. containers) of other files and you can only add whole members to them. To use it you will need to first create a CSV file, and then add it to a separate ZIP archive. The `gzip` module supports streaming uncompressed data into a gzip compressed file, but the result is not an archive of files, it's just a single compressed chunk of data.

Comment: Thanks @martineau ; yes I know about gzip, but I wanted to make this more flexible and allow zip output too. I can in fact already write individual *lines* to a text file inside a zip archive. I use the same code as above (the one that fails with DictWriter), but the writing command is like `csvfile.write(bytes(rec + '\n', encoding = 'utf-8'))`, where `rec` is the text line. Maybe this could be a way around in fact, but I would have to create myself the lines as comma-separated values in the same order as `fieldnames`. Possible but clunky. I was hoping for something  that worked OOB.

Comment: That `csvfile.write()` call is writing lines inside a CSV *file*, not a zip archive.

Comment: `with zip.open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile` defines `csvfile` as a csv file *inside a zip archive*. At least that is what the documentation says. In any case, if you say that `DictWriter` cannot do that, I guess that is not a viable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`codecs.StreamWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamWriter) if you want to use `csv.DictWriter` with binary file-handle, consider following simple example

```
import csv
import codecs
utf8 = codecs.getwriter('utf_8') # or other encoding dictated by requirements
with open("file.csv","wb") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(utf8(f), fieldnames = ['a','b','c'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows([{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}])
```

creates `file.csv` holding

```
a,b,c
1,,
,2,
,,3
```

Comment: Thanks Daweo; sorry, I am not sure how this addresses my question. I can already write a simple csv. I cannot write a *zipped* csv straight from the list of dictionaries. That was the whole point of my post.

Comment: @user6376297 you have binary file handle opened for writing (named `csvfile`), my example shows how to use `csv.DictWriter` with such file handle

Comment: I do apologise. I had not understood how I could combine the two methods.  Got it now. your file f is my csvfile, which in turn is a file inside a zip archive. I tried it out now, and it works. Thank you very much!